# Does putting Dropbox folder on an exFAT formatted external drive make it portable between Mac and PC?

Tags: windows, macos, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, dropbox

If I use an exFAT formatted external drive to house my Dropbox folder, will the folder become portable between a Mac and a PC? In other words, if I move the external hard drive between my Mac and PC, will Dropbox on either machine work with the drive plugged in?

My concern is, if the Dropbox folder contains some metadata that are OS-dependent, moving it between Mac and PC may cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

Where your Dropbox syncs to will have no effect on whether your computer can read an exFAT drive, and simply having a drive that both computers can read will not automatically make Dropbox sync the same on both.  If both your computers are configured to read exFAT and both of your Dropbox applications are configured to sync to the drive letter and folder where you placed it on the external drive, then it will sync no matter which computer you happen to have it plugged in to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My concern is, if the Dropbox folder contains some metadata that are OS-dependent, moving it between Mac and PC may cause issues.

Comment: Also, to clarify, I am referring to using the same Dropbox account and syncing to the same location.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a Dropbox account on the same drive between MacOs and Windows is currently impossible because Dropbox requires NTFS on Windows, and HFS+ or APFS on MacOs.

It can be set up on one OS and used as a regular folder on another but with no support by the app.

Feature proposals to support exFat have been requested and rejected.